# Language Translations not working in Bookworm

Tags: release-loki, vala

I have followed the instructions at the Elementary Getting Started ([Translations](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#Adding-Translations))
to set up the translations and I have a few translated languages including French in the po directory (fr.po). I can also see the file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/bookworm.mo is present. However when I run Bookworm with:

```
LANGUAGE=fr bookworm
```

I dont see the translated strings in french. Only the About Dialog has the translations showing up. Using the same command with Noise works great and I have compared the translations and CMakeLists for Noise but could not find any differences.

The bookworm code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm) for anyone wanting to take a look at the CMakeFiles.txt.
Appreciate any pointers on what I may be doing wrong in the code for the translated strings not working.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was due to a line in the code pointing at a wrong place for the translations:

```
Intl.bindtextdomain(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, "./locale");
```

Many thanks to Corentin Noel for spotting the issue.

Comment: Mark your question as solved!